# Script Failure because of Large Arrays

Tags: arrays, perl, memory, file-handling

My current script runs through data from a PDB and stores them to arrays then those arrays are used for the rest of the script. The script runs very well on a small PDB file but when I use a real PDB file I end up using all the computers memory on just one PDB file. I have 2000 PDB files I need calculations done on.

This is my full current script with a few notes.

Full script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

#my $inputfile = $ARGV[0];
#my $inputfile = '8ns_emb_alt_test.pdb';
my $inputfile = '8ns_emb_alt_101.pdb';

open( INPUTFILE, "<", $inputfile ) or die $!;

my @array = <INPUTFILE>;

### Protein
my $protein = 'PROT';
my @protx;
my @proty;
my @protz;

for ( my $line = 0; $line <= $#array; ++$line ) {
    if ( ( $array[$line] =~ m/\s+$protein\s+/ ) ) {
        chomp $array[$line];
        my @splitline = ( split /\s+/, $array[$line] );
        push @protx, $splitline[5];    #This has 2083 x-coordinates
        push @proty, $splitline[6];    #this has 2083 y-coordinates
        push @protz, $splitline[7];    #this has 2083 z-coordinates
    }
}

### Lipid
my $lipid1 = 'POPS';
my $lipid2 = 'POPC';
my @lipidx;
my @lipidy;
my @lipidz;

for ( my $line = 0; $line <= $#array; ++$line ) {
    if ( ( $array[$line] =~ m/\s+$lipid1\s+/ ) || ( $array[$line] =~ m/\s+$lipid2\s+/ ) ) {
        chomp $array[$line];
        my @splitline = ( split /\s+/, $array[$line] );
        push @lipidx, $splitline[5];    #this has approximately 35,000 x coordinates
        push @lipidy, $splitline[6];    #same as above for y
        push @lipidz, $splitline[7];    #same as above for z
    }
}

### Calculation
my @deltaX = map {
    my $diff = $_;
    map { $diff - $_ } @lipidx
} @protx;    #so this has 2083*35000 data x-coordinates
my @squared_deltaX = map { $_ * $_ } @deltaX;    #this has all the x-coordinates squared from @deltaX

my @deltaY = map {
    my $diff = $_;
    map { $diff - $_ } @lipidy
} @proty;
my @squared_deltaY = map { $_ * $_ } @deltaY;

my @deltaZ = map {
    my $diff = $_;
    map { $diff - $_ } @lipidz
} @protz;
my @squared_deltaZ = map { $_ * $_ } @deltaZ;

my @distance;
for ( my $ticker = 0; $ticker <= $#array; ++$ticker ) {
    my $distance_calc = sqrt( ( $squared_deltaX[$ticker] + $squared_deltaY[$ticker] + $squared_deltaZ[$ticker] ) );
    push @distance, $distance_calc;
}    #this runs the final calculation and computes all the distances between the atoms

### The Hunt
my $limit = 5;
my @DistU50;
my @resid_tagger;

for ( my $tracker = 0; $tracker <= $#array; ++$tracker ) {
    my $dist = $distance[$tracker];
    if ( ( $dist < $limit ) && ( $array[$tracker] =~ m/\s+$protein\s+/ ) ) {
        my @splitline = ( split /\s+/, $array[$tracker] );
        my $LT50 = $dist;
        push @resid_tagger, $splitline[4];    #selects stores a selected index number
        push @DistU50,      $LT50;            #stores the values within the $limit
    }
} #this 'for' loop search for all the elements in the '@distance' and pushes them to the final arrays and also makes an array of certain index numbers in to another array.

### Le'Finali
print "@resid_tagger = resid \n";
print "5 > @DistU50 \n";

close INPUTFILE;
```

One of my lab friends said that I could store some of the data into files so that it takes up less memory. I think that is a fine idea but I am not sure where would be the most efficient place to do that and how many times would I have to do that. I did this with arrays because it is the best way I knew how to do this.

If anyone could show me an example of where I could take an array and turn it into a file and then use the data in that file again that would be really helpful. Otherwise, if any ones has an idea that I can look up, things to try or just suggestions that would be at least start me somewhere.

Comment: I am not a chemist... I have no idea what you're doing exactly.  Personally, if I was working with large datasets... I would use a database. (but I'm sure there's a good chance that you need functions that you can't mimic in a db, too...)

Comment: Well it just finds the distance between coordinates in a file. I dont really know what you mean by use a database and the problem is dealing with the arrays. I have made some large arrays and through the script they are used in various ways. I am just trying to find away so that less information is being used by the memory of my computer.

Comment: Yeah.  Personally, I would parse the files and load them into tables in a database because they're meant to handle large data and calculations.  [is this what we're talking about?](http://www.cgl.ucsf.edu/chimera/docs/UsersGuide/tutorials/pdbintro.html)

Comment: Yea that is the exact kind of file I am using. If you want to show me an example of parsing  them into a table that would be really help, if you can.

Comment: okay.  i will.... hey, quick question.  in the file format, is there always whitespace separating values?  or can it run together (and is based specifically on column position for when a value starts/stops)?  (I skimmed that link I posted... lol, sorry)  Also... do you have a database to use?  Mysql or sql server?

Comment: There are always white spaces luckily! I was just looking up what data bases are... I am using Linux so I think MySQL is the way to go but I am highly ignorant when it comes to this kind of stuff.

Comment: @ChemistnotaProgrammer I noticed you posted a comment on my answer but it's now deleted...is there anything I need to explain further?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**edit.....**

you guys... we should have checked first.  you might want to look into the perl modules that already exist for processing and manipulating PDB data.

- http://search.cpan.org/~rulix/Bio-PDB-Structure-0.02/lib/Bio/PDB/Structure.pm
- http://www.iu.a.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~tterada/softwares/pdb.html
- http://www.perlmol.org/pod/Chemistry/File/PDB.html
- http://comp.chem.nottingham.ac.uk/parsepdb/
- http://www.perl.com/pub/2001/11/16/perlbio2.html
- https://www.biostars.org/p/89300/ (forum post, not library)

---

Okay... so perl is not my first language and I don't know *exactly* what your data looks like.

**edit:** there was  weird row in my test data.  there are two sets of code here... one splits on whitespace and the other uses expected/known column positions and length for determining values.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use DBI; 

my $db   = 'test'; 
my $host = 'localhost'; 
my $user = 'root';
my $pass = ''; 

my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:mysql:$db:$host",$user,$pass) 
            or die "Connection Error: $DBI::errstr\n";

my $localpath = 'C:\path\to\folder\with\datums';

my @filenames = ('glucagon');  # i am using this as my table name, too 
my $colnum    = 12;  # number of columns in data, I assumed this was fixed

my @placehoders; 
for (1..$colnum) { push @placehoders, '?'; } 
my $placeholders = join(',',@placehoders);   # builds a string like:  ?, ?, ?, ?, ...
                                             # for our query that uses binding 
foreach my $file (@filenames) {
   my $filename = "$localpath\\$file.txt"; 

   if (open(my $fh => $filename)) {  

      # the null at the start of the insert is because my first column is an 
      # auto_incrememnt primary key that will be generated on insert by the db 
      my $stmt = $dbh->prepare("insert into $file values (null, $placeholders)");

      while(my $line = <$fh>) {
         $line =~ s/\s+$//; # trim whitespace

         if ($line ne q{}) {  # if not totally blank
            my @row = split(/ +/,$line); # split on whitespace

            for my $index (1..$colnum) { 
               $stmt->bind_param($index, $row[$index]);
               $index++;
            }
            $stmt->execute(); 
         }
      }
      close $fh; 
   }
   else {  print "$file not opened\n";  }
}
```

```
-- i didn't know appropriate names for any of it 
create table glucagon (
   row_id   int unsigned auto_increment primary key,
   name    varchar(10),
   seq     int,
   code1   varchar(5),
   code2   varchar(5),
   code3   varchar(5),
   code4   int,
   val1    decimal(10,2),
   val2    decimal(10,2),
   val3    decimal(10,2),
   val4    decimal(10,2),
   val5    decimal(10,2),
   code5   varchar(5)
)
```

the following is found in `C:\path\to\folder\with\datums\glucagon.txt`

```
ATOM   1058  N   ARG A 141      -6.466  12.036 -10.348  7.00 19.11           N
ATOM   1059  CA  ARG A 141      -7.922  12.248 -10.253  6.00 26.80           C
ATOM   1060  C   ARG A 141      -8.119  13.499  -9.393  6.00 28.93           C
ATOM   1061  O   ARG A 141      -7.112  13.967  -8.853  8.00 28.68           O
ATOM   1062  CB  ARG A 141      -8.639  11.005  -9.687  6.00 24.11           C
ATOM   1063  CG  ARG A 141      -8.153  10.551  -8.308  6.00 19.20           C
ATOM   1064  CD  ARG A 141      -8.914   9.319  -7.796  6.00 21.53           C
ATOM   1065  NE  ARG A 141      -8.517   9.076  -6.403  7.00 20.93           N
ATOM   1066  CZ  ARG A 141      -9.142   8.234  -5.593  6.00 23.56           C
ATOM   1067  NH1 ARG A 141     -10.150   7.487  -6.019  7.00 19.04           N
ATOM   1068  NH2 ARG A 141      -8.725   8.129  -4.343  7.00 25.11           N
ATOM   1069  OXT ARG A 141      -9.233  14.024  -9.296  8.00 40.35           O
TER    1070      ARG A 141
HETATM 1071 FE   HEM A   1       8.128   7.371 -15.022 24.00 16.74          FE
HETATM 1072  CHA HEM A   1       8.617   7.879 -18.361  6.00 17.74           C
HETATM 1073  CHB HEM A   1      10.356  10.005 -14.319  6.00 18.92           C
HETATM 1074  CHC HEM A   1       8.307   6.456 -11.669  6.00 11.00           C
HETATM 1075  CHD HEM A   1       6.928   4.145 -15.725  6.00 13.25           C
```

end result...

```
mysql> select * from glucagon;
+--------+--------+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+-------+--------+-------+-------+-------+
| row_id | name   | seq  | code1 | code2 | code3 | code4 | val1   | val2  | val3   | val4  | val5  | code5 |
+--------+--------+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+-------+--------+-------+-------+-------+
|      1 | ATOM   | 1058 | N     | ARG   | A     |   141 |  -6.47 | 12.04 | -10.35 |  7.00 | 19.11 | N     |
|      2 | ATOM   | 1059 | CA    | ARG   | A     |   141 |  -7.92 | 12.25 | -10.25 |  6.00 | 26.80 | C     |
|      3 | ATOM   | 1060 | C     | ARG   | A     |   141 |  -8.12 | 13.50 |  -9.39 |  6.00 | 28.93 | C     |
|      4 | ATOM   | 1061 | O     | ARG   | A     |   141 |  -7.11 | 13.97 |  -8.85 |  8.00 | 28.68 | O     |
|      5 | ATOM   | 1062 | CB    | ARG   | A     |   141 |  -8.64 | 11.01 |  -9.69 |  6.00 | 24.11 | C     |
|      6 | ATOM   | 1063 | CG    | ARG   | A     |   141 |  -8.15 | 10.55 |  -8.31 |  6.00 | 19.20 | C     |
|      7 | ATOM   | 1064 | CD    | ARG   | A     |   141 |  -8.91 |  9.32 |  -7.80 |  6.00 | 21.53 | C     |
|      8 | ATOM   | 1065 | NE    | ARG   | A     |   141 |  -8.52 |  9.08 |  -6.40 |  7.00 | 20.93 | N     |
|      9 | ATOM   | 1066 | CZ    | ARG   | A     |   141 |  -9.14 |  8.23 |  -5.59 |  6.00 | 23.56 | C     |
|     10 | ATOM   | 1067 | NH1   | ARG   | A     |   141 | -10.15 |  7.49 |  -6.02 |  7.00 | 19.04 | N     |
|     11 | ATOM   | 1068 | NH2   | ARG   | A     |   141 |  -8.73 |  8.13 |  -4.34 |  7.00 | 25.11 | N     |
|     12 | ATOM   | 1069 | OXT   | ARG   | A     |   141 |  -9.23 | 14.02 |  -9.30 |  8.00 | 40.35 | O     |
|     13 | TER    | 1070 | ARG   | A     | 141   |  NULL |   NULL |  NULL |   NULL |  NULL |  NULL | NULL  |
|     14 | HETATM | 1071 | FE    | HEM   | A     |     1 |   8.13 |  7.37 | -15.02 | 24.00 | 16.74 | FE    |
|     15 | HETATM | 1072 | CHA   | HEM   | A     |     1 |   8.62 |  7.88 | -18.36 |  6.00 | 17.74 | C     |
|     16 | HETATM | 1073 | CHB   | HEM   | A     |     1 |  10.36 | 10.01 | -14.32 |  6.00 | 18.92 | C     |
|     17 | HETATM | 1074 | CHC   | HEM   | A     |     1 |   8.31 |  6.46 | -11.67 |  6.00 | 11.00 | C     |
|     18 | HETATM | 1075 | CHD   | HEM   | A     |     1 |   6.93 |  4.15 | -15.73 |  6.00 | 13.25 | C     |
+--------+--------+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+-------+--------+-------+-------+-------+
18 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

ohh... look... this row makes it dirty... `TER    1070      ARG A 141`.   i can easily fix this if you go my route but if you use the other answer/approach, i'm not going to bother to update this.

---

okay... for the stupid row.  I went through and counted the starting position and length of each value in my test dataset.  I didn't know if that information changes for you or not when you load different files or what... so I made it in a way that it can be set for each file you use.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use DBI;  

my $db   = 'test'; 
my $host = 'localhost'; 
my $user = 'root';
my $pass = ''; 

my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:mysql:$db:$host",$user,$pass) 
            or die "Connection Error: $DBI::errstr\n";

my $localpath = 'C:\path\to\datums'; 

                                # first num is starting pos, second is length
my $fileinfo = { 'glucagon' => [[0,6],   #  'name'
                                [7,4],   #  'seq'
                                [12,4],  #  'code1'
                                [17,3],  #  'code2'
                                [21,1],  #  'code3'
                                [23,3],  #  'code4'
                                [27,12], #  'val1'
                                [39,7],  #  'val2'
                                [47,7],  #  'val3'
                                [55,5],  #  'val4'
                                [61,5],  #  'val5'
                                [69,10]  #  'code5'
                                ] 
               #  'second_file' => [ [0,5], # col1 
               #                     [6,5], # col2                     
               #                   ]  
               };  # i am using this as my table name, too  

foreach my $file (keys %$fileinfo) {
   my $filename = "$localpath\\$file.txt";  

   if (open(my $fh => $filename)) {   
      my $colnum = scalar @{$fileinfo->{$file}}; 

      my @placehoders; 
      for (1..$colnum) { push @placehoders, '?'; } 
      my $placeholders = join(',',@placehoders);   # builds a string like:  ?, ?, ?, ?, ...
                                                   # for our query that uses binding 

      # the null at the start of the insert is because my first column is an 
      # auto_incrememnt primary key that will be generated on insert by the db 
      my $stmt = $dbh->prepare("insert into $file values (null, $placeholders)");

      while(my $line = <$fh>) {
         $line =~ s/\s+$//;   # trim trailing whitespace 
         if ($line ne q{}) {  # if not totally blank  
            my @row;
            my $index = 1; 
            # foreach value column position & length 
            foreach my $col (@{$fileinfo->{$file}}) {   
               my $value;
               if ($col->[0] <= length($line)) {
                  $value = substr($line,$col->[0],$col->[1]); 
                  $value =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g;  # trim trailing & leading whitespace
                  if ($value eq q{}) { undef $value; } # i like null values vs blank
               }
               $row[$index] = $value;
               $index++; 
            } 

            for my $index (1..$colnum) { 
               $stmt->bind_param($index, $row[$index]); 
            }
            $stmt->execute(); 
         }
      }
      close $fh; 
   }
   else {  print "$file not opened\n";  }
}
```

new data:

```
mysql> select * from  glucagon;
+--------+--------+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+-------+--------+-------+-------+-------+
| row_id | name   | seq  | code1 | code2 | code3 | code4 | val1   | val2  | val3   | val4  | val5  | code5 |
+--------+--------+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+-------+--------+-------+-------+-------+
|      1 | ATOM   | 1058 | N     | ARG   | A     |   141 |  -6.47 | 12.04 | -10.35 |  7.00 | 19.11 | N     |
|      2 | ATOM   | 1059 | CA    | ARG   | A     |   141 |  -7.92 | 12.25 | -10.25 |  6.00 | 26.80 | C     |
|      3 | ATOM   | 1060 | C     | ARG   | A     |   141 |  -8.12 | 13.50 |  -9.39 |  6.00 | 28.93 | C     |
|      4 | ATOM   | 1061 | O     | ARG   | A     |   141 |  -7.11 | 13.97 |  -8.85 |  8.00 | 28.68 | O     |
|      5 | ATOM   | 1062 | CB    | ARG   | A     |   141 |  -8.64 | 11.01 |  -9.69 |  6.00 | 24.11 | C     |
|      6 | ATOM   | 1063 | CG    | ARG   | A     |   141 |  -8.15 | 10.55 |  -8.31 |  6.00 | 19.20 | C     |
|      7 | ATOM   | 1064 | CD    | ARG   | A     |   141 |  -8.91 |  9.32 |  -7.80 |  6.00 | 21.53 | C     |
|      8 | ATOM   | 1065 | NE    | ARG   | A     |   141 |  -8.52 |  9.08 |  -6.40 |  7.00 | 20.93 | N     |
|      9 | ATOM   | 1066 | CZ    | ARG   | A     |   141 |  -9.14 |  8.23 |  -5.59 |  6.00 | 23.56 | C     |
|     10 | ATOM   | 1067 | NH1   | ARG   | A     |   141 | -10.15 |  7.49 |  -6.02 |  7.00 | 19.04 | N     |
|     11 | ATOM   | 1068 | NH2   | ARG   | A     |   141 |  -8.73 |  8.13 |  -4.34 |  7.00 | 25.11 | N     |
|     12 | ATOM   | 1069 | OXT   | ARG   | A     |   141 |  -9.23 | 14.02 |  -9.30 |  8.00 | 40.35 | O     |
|     13 | TER    | 1070 | NULL  | ARG   | A     |   141 |   NULL |  NULL |   NULL |  NULL |  NULL | NULL  |
|     14 | HETATM | 1071 | FE    | HEM   | A     |     1 |   8.13 |  7.37 | -15.02 | 24.00 | 16.74 | FE    |
|     15 | HETATM | 1072 | CHA   | HEM   | A     |     1 |   8.62 |  7.88 | -18.36 |  6.00 | 17.74 | C     |
|     16 | HETATM | 1073 | CHB   | HEM   | A     |     1 |  10.36 | 10.01 | -14.32 |  6.00 | 18.92 | C     |
|     17 | HETATM | 1074 | CHC   | HEM   | A     |     1 |   8.31 |  6.46 | -11.67 |  6.00 | 11.00 | C     |
|     18 | HETATM | 1075 | CHD   | HEM   | A     |     1 |   6.93 |  4.15 | -15.73 |  6.00 | 13.25 | C     |
+--------+--------+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+-------+--------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Answer (score 5):

You're trying to store ~66 million results in an array, which as you've noticed is both slow and memory intensive. Perl arrays are not great for massive calculations like this, but [`PDL`](https://metacpan.org/pod/PDL) is.

The core of your problem is to calculate the distance between a number of 3D coordinates. Let's do this for a simplified data set first just to prove we can do it:

```
  Start         End
---------    ---------
(0, 0, 0)    (1, 2, 3)
(1, 1, 1)    (1, 1, 1)
(4, 5, 6)    (7, 8, 9)
```

We can represent this data set in PDL like this:

```
use PDL;
                  # x        # y        # z    
my $start = pdl [ [0, 1, 4], [0, 1, 5], [0, 1, 6] ];
my $end   = pdl [ [1, 1, 7], [2, 1, 8], [3, 1, 9] ];
```

We now have two sets of 3D coordinates. To compute the distances, first we subtract our start coordinates from our end coordinates:

```
my $diff = $end - $start;
print $diff;
```

This outputs

```
[
 [1 0 3]
 [2 0 3]
 [3 0 3]
]
```

where the differences in the x-coordinates are in the first row, the differences in the y-coordinates are in the second row, and the differences in the z-coordinates are in the third row.

Next we have to square the differences:

```
my $squared = $diff**2;
print $squared;
```

which gives us

```
[
 [1 0 9]
 [4 0 9]
 [9 0 9]
]
```

Finally we need to sum the square of the differences for each pair of points and take the square root:

```
foreach my $i (0 .. $squared->dim(0) - 1) {
    say sqrt sum $squared($i,:);
}
```

(There's probably a better way to do this, but I haven't used PDL much.)

This prints out

```
3.74165738677394
0
5.19615242270663
```

which are our distances.

Putting it all together:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use PDL;
use PDL::NiceSlice;

my $start = pdl [ [0, 1, 4], [0, 1, 5], [0, 1, 6] ];
my $end   = pdl [ [1, 1, 7], [2, 1, 8], [3, 1, 9] ];

my $diff = $end - $start;
my $squared = $diff**2;

foreach my $i (0 .. $squared->dim(0) - 1) {
    say sqrt sum $squared($i,:);
}
```

It takes ~35 seconds on my desktop to calculate the distance between one million pairs of coordinates and write the results to a file. When I try with ten million pairs, I run out of memory, so you'll probably have to split your data set into pieces.

## Reading data from files

Here's an example that reads data in from two files, using sample input you included in an earlier question:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use PDL;
use PDL::IO::Misc;
use PDL::NiceSlice;

my $start_file = 'start.txt';
my $end_file   = 'end.txt';

my $start = rcols $start_file, [ 5..7 ];
my $end   = rcols $end_file, [ 5..7 ];

my $diff = $end - $start;
my $squared = $diff**2;
   
foreach my $i (0 .. $squared->dim(0) - 1) {
    say sqrt sum $squared($i,:);
}
```

*start.txt*

```
ATOM      1  N   GLU    1     -19.992  -2.816  36.359  0.00  0.00      PROT
ATOM      2  HT1 GLU    1     -19.781  -1.880  35.958  0.00  0.00      PROT
ATOM      3  HT2 GLU    1     -19.713  -2.740  37.358  0.00  0.00      PROT
ATOM      4  HT3 GLU    1     -21.027  -2.910  36.393  0.00  0.00      PROT
ATOM      5  CA  GLU    1     -19.344  -3.944  35.652  0.00  0.00      PROT
ATOM      6  HA  GLU    1     -19.817  -4.852  35.998  0.00  0.00      PROT
ATOM      7  CB  GLU    1     -19.501  -3.795  34.119  0.00  0.00      PROT
```

*end.txt*

```
ATOM   2084  N   POPC   1     -44.763  27.962  20.983  0.00  0.00      MEM1  
ATOM   2085  C12 POPC   1     -46.144  27.379  20.551  0.00  0.00      MEM1  
ATOM   2086  C13 POPC   1     -44.923  28.611  22.367  0.00  0.00      MEM1  
ATOM   2087  C14 POPC   1     -43.713  26.889  21.099  0.00  0.00      MEM1  
ATOM   2088  C15 POPC   1     -44.302  29.004  20.059  0.00  0.00      MEM1  
ATOM   2089 H12A POPC   1     -46.939  28.110  20.555  0.00  0.00      MEM1  
ATOM   2090 H12B POPC   1     -46.486  26.769  21.374  0.00  0.00      MEM1
```

*Output*

```
42.3946824613654
42.2903357636233
42.9320321205507
40.4541893133455
44.1770768272415
45.3936402704167
42.7174829080553
```

The `rcols` function comes from [`PDL::IO::Misc`](http://search.cpan.org/%7Echm/PDL/IO/Misc/misc.pd#rcols) and can be used to read specific columns from a file into a PDL object (in this cases, columns 5 through 7, zero-indexed).